# Simple ECM solution

Tags: gratis, text-processing, text-search, ecm

I work in a society which uses Apache 2.4.9 server on CentOS 6.5.

I'm looking for a *very simple* ECM (enterprise content manager) for some people who only needs to organize files with rights management and do full-text search online.

I found some solutions like Alfresco and Nuxeo but they have so many features I don't need... do you have some ideas? The solution must be free and must include rights management and full-text / title search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NemakiWare](http://nemakiware.com/) is like Alfresco, but smaller, simpler, with less features.

The features of NemakiWare are:

- Document upload/download
- Download browsing, creation/deletion/modification/move/etc
- Full-text search
- Rights management with files/folders/users/groups permissions

Free and open source.

*Disclaimer: I wrote part of its code.*

Comment: I just read some documentation about it and seems like what I was looking for, thanks!